# Groovy-grails sql.rows in gsp table

Tags: postgresql, grails, gsp

Hi i want to display a list of the results from my database in a gsp.I have put the resultes in a g:each but the result is coming to a line and not in the table.

My service is this:

```
def listAction(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        return sql.rows ("SELECT * FROM  mn")
```

my controller is this:

```
def list() {          
        [contacts : contactListService.listAction()]
    }
```

and gsp

```
<g:each in="${contacts}" var="contact" status="i">
                    <td>${contact.id}</td>
                    <td>${contact.name}</td>
                    <td><g:link action="edit" id="${contact.id}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</g:link>
                        <g:link action="delete" id="${contact.id}" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</g:link></td>
                </g:each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element should be wrapped in a new row.

```
<g:each in="${contacts}" var="contact" status="i">
    <tr>
       <td>${contact.id}</td>
       <td>${contact.name}</td>
       <td><g:link action="edit" id="${contact.id}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</g:link>
           <g:link action="delete" id="${contact.id}" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</g:link>
       </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Comment: I had the <tr> command outside of the g:each i must become blind

Comment: Oh that's just fine. Better to see it now, not after 3h staring at the code. (from experience).